# Is "To write. That is what I have always wanted to do." proper?

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation

> "To write. That is what I have always wanted to do."

Would it be better if I used a comma instead?
Thus:

> "To write, that is what I have always wanted to do."

I guess this flows a bit better at the cost of a tad of perceived drama. Yes, I know I might be over thinking it, that is why I decided to start off with something simple. Thank you.

Comment: The comma may mislead the reader here – to-infinitives as subjects are pretty uncommon. If you want a dramatic pause, use the sentence fragment. If you want it to run more smoothly, use a dash rather than a comma.

Comment: You could consider a dash instead of period, but the comma is definitely problematic.

Comment: It's largely an issue of style. I would probably write this: "To write: that is what I have always wanted to do."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for writing advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "To write. That is what I have always wanted to do."
>
> Would it be better if I used a comma instead? Thus:
>
> "To write, that is what I have always wanted to do."

"To write." Using a period, which is an end punctuation terminating a sentence is nonstandard with only a phrase. A phrase may have a subject and no verb, or the other way around, a verb but no subject. In any case, it is not a sentence. The phrase "to write" can be used as a prepositional phrase or an infinitive phrase in a sentence.

By using a comma with the phrase at the beginning of your sentence, you incorporate it into the sentence as a *noun infinitive phrase* which is the antecedent of the pronoun *that*. The pronoun is the subject in your sentence.

"To write, that is what I have always wanted to do."

Means...

"To write, to write is what I have always wanted to do."

It's also the antecedent for "what"

"To write, to write is to write I have always wanted to do." [what I have always wanted to do is to write]

To write | to write (that) | is | to write (what) I have always wanted to do

So, you can drop the pronoun "that" and just use the noun infinitive phrase:

To write is what I have always wanted to do. = What I have always wanted to do is to write.

BEST: To write is what I have always wanted to do.

Comment: Punctuation can very well follow incomplete sentences. Especially in speech. "Yes, Sir." Thus, I think you are overanalyzing this as a sentence rather than a fragment. Consider Edwin's comment at the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a phrase with a comma at the start of your sentence like that, a good test to see if it is correct is to try to rearrange your sentence so that you don't need the comma.

Here's an example:

> Before I started exercising, I stretched.

I can rearrange this sentence like this and still make sense:

> I stretched before I started exercising.

Here is your sentence:

> To write, that is what I have always wanted to do.

With this sentence, it is impossible to decide what the phrase "to write" is modifying!

The reason for this is that "to write" is not a prepositional or adjective phrase. It is a verb in an infinitive form. You cannot use an infinitive verb in this way in English. It is simpler, more effective, and grammatically correct to write this:

> I have always wanted to write.

Or this:

> What I have always wanted to do is to write.

But, as you can see, if we try to arrange your sentence as written into something that makes sense without the comma, it just doesn't work!

> That is what I have always wanted to do.

ADDENDUM:

If you still want to phrase your sentence more or less the same, you can use commas and a different sentence structure to do it correctly. The trick here is to use your infinitive, "to write", as the elaborated antecedent of "that".

> That, to write, is what I have always wanted to do.

If you do it this way, though, it might be clearer to many readers if you use em dashes instead of commas.

> That--to write--is what I have always wanted to do.

Comment: Good answer, I think, but I'm puzzled by your avoidance of "to write" as the subject of the sentence: "To write is what I have always wanted to do."  Both infinitives and gerunds can be used pretty much anywhere you would use any noun.

Comment: Sure, that's also a fine way to do it. I wasn't avoiding the infinitive as the subject for any specific reason. More that I was in a hurry. :) There are many other ways that sentence can be rearranged, also. I feel it's not productive to list all of them, as long as the examples given are sufficient to explain the idea.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most well-known texts in English starts with the phrase

> To be, or not to be: that is the question: (...)

The punctuation varies between sources: in the Bard's first editions, commas were used instead of colons, but in modern punctuation and recent sources the colons are used more often.

Therefore, you can write

> To write: that is what I have always wanted to do.

And you'll have Shakespear on your side if anyone complains.

Comment: There's also a [well known song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Impossible_Dream_(The_Quest)) whose [lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/the-impossible-dream-lyrics-andy-williams.html) go: "To dream the impossible dream / (other infinitive phrases) / To reach the unreachable star // This is my quest, to follow that star, No matter how hopeless, no matter how far ..." Unfortunately, since this is a song, it's hard to know what punctuation the author intended to put between the infinitives and the "This".

Answer (score 0):

Writing is an art form. Writers use punctuation as a tool to help express what they want to say (especially in the type of writing your question illustrates). There is nothing improper about using a statement such as *to write*. I use "statement" because what constitutes a complete sentence is disputed. Does it have to contain a verb? What about the statement: *Food*? That can contain a thought, perhaps even a complete thought on the page that serves as the writer's canvas. Punctuation that you can see exists only in written English. We can use pauses in spoken English. It is not improper to say

"To write to teach to dance I want to do all three"

using appropriate pauses. Some people say that punctuation in written English represents the different types or length of pauses in speech. Maybe.